# Meaning of как раз-таки

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, наречия

I read the following passage:

> Я понимаю, но в русской традиции, если можно так выразиться, это
>   событие **как раз-таки** имеет название - высадка.

Did they mean to write **это событие как раз так и имеет название**,  or is this an actual word? If so, what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a real colloquial expression of disagreement with something just said. It doesn't unfold into expression you've suggested. Most likely, the other person mentioned some exception (like 'this event happens to have no Russian word for it'), then their opponent uses "**как раз(-таки)**" to catch at their words, meaning that very exception *proves otherwise*, like it's a rare case where that event actually *has* a Russian word for it. The part "**-таки**" which gives an extra sense of "**although one can think so**", is optional here and maybe a bit informal for written language. It is more typical as a part of "**всё-таки**" (still, despite smth.).

Answer (score 14):

*Как раз* and *-таки* are emphatic particles, similar to emphatic "do" in English, but slightly differing in meaning.

> Я купил хлеба / I bought some bread
>
> Я-таки купил хлеба / I did buy some bread (after having failed to do this)
>
> Я-то как раз купил хлеба / I did buy some bread (unlike someone else)

So *-таки* is a slight misuse here, it is just used to give more stress to the argument.

The phrase means:

> I understand, but the Russian tradition, if I may say so, does have a name for this event: высадка.

Comment: In third example I would say "Как раз я-то купил хлеба". Also it's strange why answer downvoted, because it is good.

Comment: "Я таки купил хлеба" and "... как раз таки ..." seem to be the correct way to write it. [Use of the hyphen](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=6714) with the particles can be rather tricky, and since you rarely use these constructions in writing, it's easy to make a mistake.